# WPF live sorting of groups

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For example in XAML with a list of items, which is grouped and sorted:

```
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="collectionViewSource" Source="{Binding Items}" IsLiveGroupingRequested="True" IsLiveSortingRequested="True">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <ComponentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Group.Rating" />
                    <ComponentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="ID" />
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <CollectionViewSource.LiveGroupingProperties>
                    <System:String>Group</System:String>
                </CollectionViewSource.LiveGroupingProperties>
                <CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
                    <System:String>Group.Rating</System:String>
                </CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource collectionViewSource}}" />
```

If the group's sorting key can be changed, the groups are not reordered even though live grouping and live sorting are enabled.

What am I missing?

Comment: Apparently, live sorting on a nested property doesn't work when the items are grouped. You may work around this by calling `View.Refresh()` on the `CollectionViewSource` in the event handlers.

Comment: @mm8 "nested property": Does it work on non-nested properties?

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: So WPF Live Sorting of groups is broken in all cases? Calling `View.Refresh()` from event handlers is not trivial / possible in complex applications. Re-creating the group object when re-sorting is needed seems another workaround.